# Parsing Azure Blob Queue Message in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-queues

I use the Azure Data Factory Web Activity to get Queue Messages from azure blob storage.

```
{
    "Response": "
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<QueueMessagesList>
    <QueueMessage>
        <MessageId>12345678</MessageId>
        <InsertionTime>Mon, 12 Jun 2023 07:31:05 GMT</InsertionTime>
        <ExpirationTime>Mon, 19 Jun 2023 07:31:05 GMT</ExpirationTime>
        <PopReceipt>AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAAT8iLmwid2QE=</PopReceipt>
        <TimeNextVisible>Mon, 12 Jun 2023 08:33:47 GMT</TimeNextVisible>
        <DequeueCount>25</DequeueCount>
        <MessageText>12062023/test1.csv</MessageText>
    </QueueMessage>
    <QueueMessage>
        <MessageId>45678910</MessageId>
        <InsertionTime>Mon, 12 Jun 2023 07:30:42 GMT</InsertionTime>
        <ExpirationTime>Mon, 19 Jun 2023 07:30:42 GMT</ExpirationTime>
        <PopReceipt>AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAAT8iLmwid2QE=</PopReceipt>
        <TimeNextVisible>Mon, 12 Jun 2023 08:33:47 GMT</TimeNextVisible>
        <DequeueCount>25</DequeueCount>
        <MessageText>12062023/test2.csv</MessageText>
    </QueueMessage>
    <QueueMessage>
        <MessageId>1112012323</MessageId>
        <InsertionTime>Mon, 12 Jun 2023 08:33:08 GMT</InsertionTime>
        <ExpirationTime>Mon, 19 Jun 2023 08:33:08 GMT</ExpirationTime>
        <PopReceipt>AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAAT8iLmwid2QE=</PopReceipt>
        <TimeNextVisible>Mon, 12 Jun 2023 08:33:47 GMT</TimeNextVisible>
        <DequeueCount>1</DequeueCount>
        <MessageText>11062023/test3.csv</MessageText>
    </QueueMessage>
</QueueMessagesList>",
    "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "x-ms-request-id": "jksasjkacas",
        "x-ms-version": "2020-04-08",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Date": "Mon, 12 Jun 2023 08:33:17 GMT",
        "Server": "Windows-Azure-Queue/1.0;Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
        "Content-Type": "application/xml"
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "Runtime2",
    "executionDuration": 0,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to get this output and feed each MessageText into ForEach and run next pipeline process.

In ForEach Items, i used:

```
@split(activity('get_queue_message').output.Response, '</MessageText>')
```

Within ForEach i have a SetVariable with the following value:

```
@split(item(), '<MessageText>')[1]
```

This configuration manages to return me the 3 MessageText in the sample above. But it always have an extra Set Variable run that results in error:

> The expression 'split(item(), '')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgpC6.png)' cannot be evaluated because array index '1' is >outside bounds (0, 0) of array.

[image]

Please can you help to see where I have done wrong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- I have taken the given response as a parameter value of object type. When I have used the same dynamic content, it got the same error:

[image]

- This is because the 1st index element of the array we are trying to access does not exist. The following is the value of this array (the one where the step fails):

```
{ 
    "variableName": "tp2", 
    "value": " </QueueMessage> </QueueMessagesList>" 
}
```

[image]

- Since we are using `@split(item(), '<MessageText>')[1]` to split and there is no `<MessageText>` in the string, the error is occurring. So, check if the `<MessageText>` string is present or not before splitting the string to avoid errors.
- I have used the following dynamic content instead of `@split(item(), '<MessageText>')[1]` to get the actual output:

```
@if(contains(item(),'<MessageText>'),split(item(),'<MessageText>')[1],'no message text')
```

[image]

- When you run the pipeline, you get all the required information, but when there is no `<MessageText>`, the above condition assigns the variable the value of `no message text`.

[image]

- The following is the complete pipeline JSON:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@split(pipeline().parameters.response.Response,'</MessageText>')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "1st index array value",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "current string",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "tp",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@if(contains(item(),'<MessageText>'),split(item(),'<MessageText>')[1],'no message text')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "current string",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "tp2",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@item()",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "response": {
                "type": "object",
                "defaultValue": {
                    "Response": " <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> <QueueMessagesList>     <QueueMessage>         <MessageId>12345678</MessageId>         <InsertionTime>Mon, 12 Jun 2023 07:31:05 GMT</InsertionTime>         <ExpirationTime>Mon, 19 Jun 2023 07:31:05 GMT</ExpirationTime>         <PopReceipt>AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAAT8iLmwid2QE=</PopReceipt>         <TimeNextVisible>Mon, 12 Jun 2023 08:33:47 GMT</TimeNextVisible>         <DequeueCount>25</DequeueCount>         <MessageText>12062023/test1.csv</MessageText>     </QueueMessage>     <QueueMessage>         <MessageId>45678910</MessageId>         <InsertionTime>Mon, 12 Jun 2023 07:30:42 GMT</InsertionTime>         <ExpirationTime>Mon, 19 Jun 2023 07:30:42 GMT</ExpirationTime>         <PopReceipt>AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAAT8iLmwid2QE=</PopReceipt>         <TimeNextVisible>Mon, 12 Jun 2023 08:33:47 GMT</TimeNextVisible>         <DequeueCount>25</DequeueCount>         <MessageText>12062023/test2.csv</MessageText>     </QueueMessage>     <QueueMessage>         <MessageId>1112012323</MessageId>         <InsertionTime>Mon, 12 Jun 2023 08:33:08 GMT</InsertionTime>         <ExpirationTime>Mon, 19 Jun 2023 08:33:08 GMT</ExpirationTime>         <PopReceipt>AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAAT8iLmwid2QE=</PopReceipt>         <TimeNextVisible>Mon, 12 Jun 2023 08:33:47 GMT</TimeNextVisible>         <DequeueCount>1</DequeueCount>         <MessageText>11062023/test3.csv</MessageText>     </QueueMessage> </QueueMessagesList>",
                    "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
                        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
                        "x-ms-request-id": "jksasjkacas",
                        "x-ms-version": "2020-04-08",
                        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                        "Date": "Mon, 12 Jun 2023 08:33:17 GMT",
                        "Server": "Windows-Azure-Queue/1.0;Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
                        "Content-Type": "application/xml"
                    },
                    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "Runtime2",
                    "executionDuration": 0,
                    "durationInQueue": {
                        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
                    },
                    "billingReference": {
                        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
                        "billableDuration": [
                            {
                                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                                "unit": "Hours"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "tp": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "tp2": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Saideep, thank you. It works, but is there any way that we can avoid having empty message? I tried parsing it as XML but does not seem to work..

Comment: Hey @soiryk139, the above is not happening because of empty message but because of the split. The response ends with `<MessageText>11062023/test3.csv</MessageText></QueueMessage></QueueMessagesList>` and since you have split using `</MessageText>` the item value for last iteration would be `</QueueMessage></QueueMessagesList>`. Since there is no <MessageText> in this item, you cannot access the 1st index element and hence the error. Using the above logic gives desired result.

Comment: Hey @soiryk139, even when the <QueueMessagesList> is empty (meaning there are no QueueMessage and thus no MessageText) as we are checking it using the dynamic content given in the solution.